# AutoHotkey's for the arrow keys

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to hold

```
alt + spacebar + U for the up key
alt + spacebar + H for the left arrow key
alt + spacebar + J for the right arrow key
alt  +spacebar + N for the down arrow
```

is this possible to do with AutoHotkey?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello and welcome to AutoHotkey,

you might want to have a look at the basic introduction to the heart of AHK, Hotkeys:

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm

Configuring hotkeys which do nothing but send another key is fairly simple. For example, `alt + spacebar for the up key` could be translated into

```
!Space::
    send {up}
return
```

(note that `alt` is a modifier and can be written as `!`)
or short form:

```
!Space::send {up}
```

`spacebar + U for the up key` would be `Space & U::send {up}`.

But you are seeking for 2 keys PLUS a modifier (alt). For a hotkeylabel triggered by more than just two keys (`alt + space + u`), you'll need a workaround:

```
!Space::    ; once alt + space was pressed, ...
    while(getKeyState("alt") || getKeyState("space") || getKeyState("u")) { ; ... while either of these is being pressed down, ...
        hotKey, *u, altSpaceU, ON   ; u should now send {up}
    }
    hotKey, *u, altSpaceU, OFF
return

altSpaceU:  ; note: this is a label, no hotkey
    send {up}
return
```

Please, don't be undeterred by this. AutoHotkey is actually quite powerful and easy to learn. Sadly, (afaik) this is the only working way to solve more-than-two-key-hotkeys.

EDIT
jesus why didnt anybody tell me..

```
#if getkeystate("alt")
!space::send {up}
#if
```

is obviously a way better solution

Comment: Awesome thanks!! this is great, the !u etc works great. it is mainly for writing code so i don't have to move my right hand all the way over to the arrow keys, lazy I know but if there were arrow keys under the space bar it would be perfect.

Comment: "the !u etc"? So you came up with `!u::send {up}`? well that was easy. Yes, ahk is just for the lazy ppl :p

You might want to answer your own question then so you can accept some answer. Otherwise, others will see this as unsolved.

See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Just want to point out that `Space & U::send {up}` prevents the Spacebar from working

Comment: @Diego you need to add a `~` before the keyname (see link in answer)

Comment: @Blauhirn thanks.. this solves one problem, but it creates another one. Say I press Space + J to move to the left, it creates a space before moving left. How can I prevent the space from creating the space right before the hotkey is triggered? Sleep option?

Comment: @Diego https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo says something about "Fire on release" which seems to be what you want. But I dont know how you can do fire on release while keeping original functionality with the key. You should probably open up a new question for this

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution
!Space::
    send {up}
return